# Create a secure connection for internal services with SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication, signalr

I'm working with a SignalR server application that is available via the Internet. It implements a regular authentication based on credentials. I'm now working on another service that I'd like to hook up to this server with access to a different set of functions as opposed to my regular users. I could create a special internal user with a different role and hardcode it (its login and password) in my internal app as by definition the binary wouldn't even be available anywhere, but for some reason it seems fishy to me.

I've also thought about creating a secondary SignalR server that would listen on a different port but only internally in my VPN, behind a firewall (the service will be hosted with Amazon VPC). The issue with that solution is the obvious need to create a second server application.

What should I do? How do you handle internal APIs and their authentication?

Answer (score 0):

**Use ASP.NET Identity**

Details see:
https://www.asp.net/identity

How to use with signalr:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization